# How do I make small texture scale without blurring the image? Like Minecraft?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I use these modes for OPENGL

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

and I'm using this code to draw the texture

```
    texture.bind();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(x, y);// Upper Left

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(x + width, y); // Upper right

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(x + width, y + heigth); // Lower right

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(x, y + heigth); // Lower left
    glEnd();
```

The texture it self is from Minecraft and is a 16x16 texture. but when I scale it to 160x160 I get a result of :

[image]

Comment: There's similar question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19075/how-can-i-make-opengl-textures-scale-without-becoming-blurry

Comment: @PawełPiecyk I've read that, it didn't work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` & `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`.

If you want to keep the pixel look to the texture, you would do the following.

```
texture.bind(); // First you bind your texture
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

and if you want them back to being "blury", you would do the following.

```
texture.bind(); // First you bind your texture
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Remember that for multiple textures you need to call them individually, like this.

```
texture1.bind();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

texture2.bind();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: Ohh, sorry I accidentally flipped the `GL_NEAREST` & `GL_LINEAR`. Look at updated answer.

Comment: You can also use Sampler objects in OpenGL 3.3+ to vastly simplify the process of changing a texture filter on-the-fly. Instead of changing these sates per-texture, you setup a sampler object with the filter states you want and then just change the bound sampler object. This is how it worked in D3D (texture filter was a sampler state, and not per-texture) for years, and should have worked in OpenGL as well - it should be the preferred methodology in modern OpenGL graphics engines.

Comment: You probably still want to do mipmapping and filtering even when you want the textures to look blocky up close. I'd set the value for `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. Although, noticing you're using `glOrtho`, perhaps you never see use the textures at a distance where minification happens.